# Perl LibXML get last line number of Node

Tags: html, xml, perl, libxml2

I use LibXML in Perl, which store the start line number of each node, but how i can get the last one?

I tried get last line number through..

- ..counting newlines in innerhtml of the node, but LibXML return the innerhtml in different formatting than original, so that the line number differ.
- ..node->getLastChild->line_number, but also havin no success.

Any Idea?

Comment: Why do you need the line number?

Comment: I do some calculations and i need the last number of some nodes that exactly match the line number in html

Comment: You can't do that with `LibXML`. But it's a strange requirement anyway as XML data should be queried and manipulated through an API such as the DOM, and the layout of the data is irrelevant. If you explain the problem you are trying to solve then I am sure we can come up with a better way.

Answer (score 0):

If `line_number` returned the first line of a node as you say, all you'd need is

```
my $s_line_num = $node->line_number();
my $e_line_num = $node->nextSibling()->line_number();
```

But it doesn't. What `line_number` returns is actually closer the number of the last line of the node. For that, we could simply look at the previous sibling's line number.

```
my $s_line_num = $node->previousSibling()->line_number();
my $e_line_num = $node->line_number();
```

But while that's what it returns for non-element nodes, it returns the last line number of the start tag (rather than of the element as a whole) for elements. That's completely useless.

Sorry, no can do!

Answer (score 0):

If line_number returned the first line of a node as you say, all you'd need is

```
my $parser = XML::LibXML->new( XML_LIBXML_LINENUMBERS==>1);


my $e_line_num = $node->line_number();
```

=> 1 );