# Perl DOM and XML source reference

Tags: xml, perl, dom, sax

Is there a way to get information about source code of the file I've parsed, when processing DOM tree? I need to get source file name and line an element starts on. In have to upgrade code of an application, to make it print errors like this: *Wrong configuration record - blah, blah... in config1.xml, line 24.*

Comment: What Perl module are you using for parsing? Here is a perhaps related question using LibXML: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14414738/perl-libxml-get-last-line-number-of-node

Comment: Probably not LibXML, because my implementation does not define `line_number` method, but thanks for your hint.

Comment: Don't tell us what parser you aren't using; tell us the one you are using. The question cannot be answered until you do.

Comment: It's irrelevant question. I haven't to use just this implementation. The LibXML, which has this special feature (`line_number` method), is available in my Perl too, thus I'm satisfied with Berlin's comment. Nevertheless there is a small problem. Several elements may be defined in a file included as system entity. Regrettably it seems to be a think, the developers of LibXML haven't dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

The `XML::DOM` module subclasses `XML::Parser`, which in turn subclasses `XML::Parser::Expat`. The last provides a `current_line` method, which returns the file line number that has been reached during the parsing process.

Although the information is available, it is up to the calling package to use it and build it into the final document tree. If this isn't done then there is no way to retrieve the information after the parse.

Depending on how much of the `XML::Parser::Expat` interface is exposed at the `XML::DOM` level, you may get some mileage from subclassing `XML::DOM`; but I would expect the changes would have to be made at the level of  `XML::DOM::Parser` or lower, and you then have the problem of persuading the calling class to use your subclass instead of the original.

Most likely you are better off using a different `XML` module that retains the information that you need after the parse. If that is possible, and `XML::LibXML` fulfils your requirement, then go for that instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My Perl contains LibXML so I can try it easily. But what shall I do to get the file name? Several parts of document can be stored separately and included from outside as a SYSTEM entity.